# Looking for ruby gem that determines programming language by reading the code?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

A couple of months ago I read a blog post about a ruby gem that could determine the programming language by reading the code itself.  For the life of me I can't recall the blog or the name of the gem.  And googling for "ruby programming language guess" and variations thereof aren't helping.

Anyone happen to know the name of the gem in question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Was it this one: http://github.com/chrislo/sourceclassifier/tree/master

Answer (score 4):

Check out the article at http://blog.chrislowis.co.uk/2009/01/04/identify-programming-languages-with-source-classifier.html.

The gem mentioned is called SourceClassifier and can be found at http://github.com/chrislo/sourceclassifier/tree/master.

Hope that is what you were looking for!